# ExpandableListView Not Updated After AsyncTask finishes executing

Tags: android, android-asynctask, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView that is created as part of an activity:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.news);

    // create the exandable list view widget
    newsListAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(this.getApplicationContext());    

    newsListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.news_list_view);

    newsListView.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);

    final Button homeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_btn);

    // go back to the home page
    homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {                
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), HomeActivity.class));
        }
    });   

    newsListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, long arg3) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    newsListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, 
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    showLoadingProgressDialog();

    downloadRssFeedTask = new DownloadRssFeedTask();

    downloadRssFeedTask.execute();
}
```

as you can see from the code, it goes off and does a pull from an RSS feed in an AsyncTask.

The AsyncTask finishes, the progress dialog is dismissed and the activity is told that the task has completed:

```
   private void responseReceived(Channel newsResponse) {
    if (newsResponse != null)           
        newsListAdapter.buildView(newsResponse);
    }
    else {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), 
                           "There is no news available at this time.", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

        toast.show();
    }
}
```

However, the ExpandableListView does not redraw/refresh itself after the data is loaded, it is a blank screen.  How do you get the ExpandableListView to refresh itself with the RSS data?  I have tried `invalidate` and `refreshDrawableState` but there was no joy.

Thoughts?

Comment: Doh! <Beats head on desk while lamenting that will not get last two hours of life back.>

The magical answer is `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the Adapter class.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you forgot to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on adapter after downloading RSS feed (probably you should call it in `onPostExecute()` method in your `AsyncTask`).

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
newsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```